# npm no instala los paquetes

Tags: nodejs, npm

Estoy tratando de instalar Electron, ya lo había hecho antes pero ahora cuando lo hago (con sudo claro) llega a un punto en que la consola dice:

> node install.js

y ahí queda no pasa nada más... al tratar de cerrar la consola me dice que el proceso esta en ejecución pero simplemente nunca se concreta, antes lo había instalado y no demoraba...

Esta es la salida en consola:

```
$ sudo npm install -g electron
/usr/local/bin/electron -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron/cli.js

> electron@1.4.7 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron
> node install.js
```

Comment: He de suponer que lo estás instalando de forma global para trabajarlo desde cualquier lugar mediante `npm i -g electron` ¿verdad? puedes quizá poner toda la ejecución en tu consola desde que empiezas a instalarlo hasta cuando llegas al punto de `node install.js` para hacernos a una mejor idea de que pueda estar pasando

Comment: eh agregado el tema de la consola, al ejecutar el comando npm install se muestra como se obtiene el arboles de archivo (con una barra de carga) etc etc esto desaparece luego y queda así

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segun este [issue](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-prebuilt/issues/27) con exactamente el mismo problema que tu :

Apartir de la version `1.3.1` existen dos ramas para instalar `electron` [Pagina oficial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron)

- electron (`npm install electron--save-dev`)
- electron-prebuilt (`npm install electron-prebuilt --save-dev`)

***Cualquier de las dos te sirve, pero `prebuilt` estara activo hasta fines del 2016***

Puedes ejecutar `npm install electron --save-dev`

Para una mejor y limpia instalación te recomiendo

```
rm -rf ~/.electron/
rm -rf ~/.atom/
npm cache clear
npm install electron--save-dev
```

Comment: He intentando instalar `electron` en mi maquina (w10) de varias formas mediante el gestor de paquetes `npm` y en todas llego al error de @Cristofer Fuentes, es bastante extraño, lo he intentado así:
`npm i -g electron`
`npm i electron --save-dev`
`npm i electron-prebuilt --save-dev`

Comment: te aconsejo que borres de la carpeta `node_modules` todo sobre electron, ya que como haz intentado varias veces puede que haya quedado algo de las instalaciones erroneas

Comment: Bueno, solo he intentando para ayudar a solucionar el problema, y ya había hecho un `npm uninstall -g electron` y borrado dichas carpetas para hacer una instalación limpia y no, siempre se tilda en `node install.js`

Comment: actualice mi respuesta, espero eso te pueda ayudar!

Comment: Hola luego de ejecutar cache clear con npm me apareció un error que antes no aparecía !  este error hacia referencia a que el problema no era de npm si no del script de instalación de electron, me di cuenta que tengo atrasada 1 version node y npm por lo cual actualizare y contare que tal

Comment: @CristoferFuentes me comentas que tal!

Comment: Al final luego de reinstalar todo y utilizar el método que me dijiste pude instalarlo de modo local, lo cual por ahora es suficiente para mi ya que puedo seguir desarrollando pero no e podido instalarlo globalmente. Gracias